# Docker Desktop Installation on Windows 10 Pro machine

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

Could you help me to resolve below error, I get below exception while Installing Docker Software in Windows 10 Pro Machine.

[image]

I did run the Docker Desktop as admin, still face the same issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a two things that might be a factor.

- Do you have any anti virus running?
- Sometimes Windows doesn't support a specific version of Docker. Double check if your Docker version is compatible with your Windows version.

Comment: Chen, Thank you really for your suggestion, I have the anti-virus running in my machine(cant disable it). I have tried to Install Docker Desktop version 3.5.1, I  get the same error as mentioned above..